# Como usar LinkedHashSet para implementar essa interface IHashSet?

Tags: java, estrutura-de-dados, hashset

Como usar `LinkedHashSet` implementando a interface `IHashSet` usando encadeamento para solucionar conflitos e com fator de carga 0.75?

```
//Usando essa interface
public interface IHashSet{
 public void put(Object data);
 public boolean contains(Object data);
 public void remove(Object data);
 public boolean isEmpty();
 public int size();
}
```

Comment: Porque você quer fazer isso? A classe `LinkedHashSet` já faz exatamente isso, então está me parecendo que você procura algo [nesse estilo](http://desciclopedia.org/wiki/Gambi_Design_Patterns#Reinvented_Square_Wheel_Wrapper), mas você não deveria estar querendo algo assim sem um bom motivo.

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro, seria boa ideia fazer essa interface ser genérica:

```
public interface IHashSet<E> {
    public void put(E data);
    public boolean contains(E data);
    public void remove(E data);
    public boolean isEmpty();
    public int size();
}
```

Todos esses métodos já existem no `LinkedHashSet`, que por padrão já usa encadeamento para resolver conflitos (colisão de *hashes*) e já 0.75 tem como o fator de carga padrão. Assim sendo basta delegar as chamadas:

```
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;

public class MyHashSet<E> implements IHashSet<E> {
    private final LinkedHashSet<E> set;

    public MyHashSet() {
        set = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    }

    @Override
    public void put(E data) {
        set.add(data);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(E data) {
        return set.contains(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(E data) {
        set.remove(data);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return set.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return set.size();
    }
}
```

No entanto, eu questiono o porquê de fazer isso. A menos que você tenha um motivo muito bom (decerto alguns existem, mas tenho minhas dúvidas neste caso), não há muito sentido fazer-se isso. A interface `IHashSet` é uma tentativa de [reinventar a roda quadrada](http://desciclopedia.org/wiki/Gambi_Design_Patterns#Reinvented_Square_Wheel_Helper) e a implementação que eu dei apenas [usa a roda redonda padrão para fazer uma roda quadrada](http://desciclopedia.org/wiki/Gambi_Design_Patterns#Reinvented_Square_Wheel_Wrapper). O ideal seria simplesmente usar a interface `java.util.Set` padrão e a implementação `java.util.LinkedHashSet` padrão, e com isso você não precisaria de `IHashSet` e nem da implementação dela.